# Google Cloud Platform - Unable to SSH to VM

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, openssl

We are unable to SSH in to a GCP VM which was working well until 2 days ago. When we try to SSH in from the GCP console, the console literally stays on this screen forever.

[image]

When attempting to connect via a putty client from my local machine, I got the error:
"No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)"

The firewall / ingress rules look good. I remember updating a docker image on the VM which required some dependencies to be updated including OpenSSL. We suspect this could be causing this, but have no way of confirming / undoing what we did.

Any idea how we can get around this problem?

Comment: Did you try to see the log in the serial port?

Comment: You can also login via the serial port for debugging ... see ... https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console

Comment: Here is another good link ... https://serverfault.com/questions/946171/google-compute-engine-ubuntu-openssl-1-1-1a

Comment: As much as I love the SSH feature in the Google Cloud Console, I have seen this problem enough that I use SSH programs to connect to my instances. For Windows, you can use the Windows ssh program. I prefer to use Bitvise. Many use Putty. Try the command `gcloud compute ssh INSTANCE_NAME`. If this works, then you have a temporary browser issue which is usually fixed by restarting.

Answer (score 0):

I have  experience delays when connecting to my instances using the SSH feature in GCP, usually it resolves after waiting a few minutes and try again, worst case I need to reboot.
As mentioned in another comment you can use [other methods to connect to your instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#thirdpartytools) (linux ssh , putty)

Your error No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)"  must be due not having [OS Login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access) enabled which is a requirement to use these methods

If you continue experiencing this issue I suggest you to share your [serial console logs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/viewing-serial-port-output)